# サブディレクトリへのアクセスがForbiddenになる

Tags: apache, django

【環境】
サーバーOS：Windows10
Apache：2.4.41
django：3.0.8
Python：Python 3.7.3

【前提】
・作成したアプリはpython manage.py runserverで動作確認済み
・他のシステムの都合上、Linux系サーバーは使えない

【Directory設定(httpd.conf)】

```
<Directory C:/apps/mysite/appname>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

【urlpatterns】

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('config', views.config, name='config'),
]
```

【現象】
djangoアプリをapache上で動作させようとした。
アプリ直下のページは正しく動作するが、サブディレクトリのページアクセスを拒否（Forbidden）される。
runserverでデバッグした際に、サブディレクトリのページが表示されるのを確認している。

http://example.com        -> 正常動作
http://example.com/config -> Forbidden

【質問】
サブディレクトリへ正しくアクセスするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
また他に確認すべき内容があればご教示ください。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: まず最初に確認すべきなのは、ディレクトリのオーナーとパーミッションだと思います。
既に調査されていますか？

Comment: "config"はファイルシステム上のサブディレクトリではなく、djangoのurlpatternsによって割り当てられます。
実ディレクトリではなく、かつOSがWindowsなので、オーナー/パーミッションは存在しないですよね？

Comment: apacheの設定方法のミスかもしれないです。どのようにApacheを設定しましたか？そちらも追記してもらえるとよいかもしれないです。それとももしかしてもしかしてhttpd.confを書き換えただけですか？